# SandboxPostCopy Profile Name

Tags: sandboxpostcopy

Does anyone know what profile name or Id a SandboxPostCopy implementation occurs in? The code that I have to run after a refresh/cloning keeps hitting a validation rule based on the profile but since the profile that SandboxPostCopy is running as is not the normal System Administrator profile I wanted to know what the Id of it was.

Comment: note there are other use cases where the running user is Automated Process - notably Platform Events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not have a profile. You can verify this by the following query:

```
SELECT Profile.Name FROM User WHERE Name = 'Automated Process'
```

As such, you'll want to use "IsBlank" to see if there is a profile name at all.

[image: Automated Process user]